# Embedding youtube into flash with actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, youtube, embed

I'm struggling to embed a youtube video into my flash project, I just can't get anything to work after hours and hours of trying to find a working tutorial and studying the api google have provided.
I want to have a player that could possibly play from a youtube playlist as the goal is to showcase live performances of a band, but I don't have a clue how to get it off of the ground!

If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import flash.system.Security;

Security.allowDomain( '*' );
Security.allowInsecureDomain( '*' );

var vPlayer:Object;
var playerLoader:Loader;

function loadVideo():void
{
    playerLoader = new Loader();

    // next line loads a youtube player with no UI
    playerLoader.load( new URLRequest( 'http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3' ) );

    // wait for it to load
    playerLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.INIT, onLoaderInit );
}

function onLoaderInit( evt:Event ):void
{
    // 'vPlayer_container' is a movieclip on stage that you need to create to hold the youtube player.
    // add your youtube Loader, ( which is actually the player ), to vPlayer_container's display list.
    vPlayer_container.addChild(playerLoader);

    // set the vPlayer variable to be the loaded youtube player
    vPlayer = playerLoader.content;

    // wait for it to be ready
    vPlayer.addEventListener( 'onReady', onPlayerReady );
}

function onPlayerReady( evt:Event ):void
{
    vPlayer.removeEventListener( 'onReady', onPlayerReady );

    // set listener for onComplete and play/pause events
    vPlayer.addEventListener( 'onStateChange', onPlayerStateChange );

    // mute it on start if you want
    vPlayer.mute();

    // set size of video screen
    vPlayer.setSize( 392,220 );

    // now load your youtube video in your new youtube player
    // get this video number off the url to your youtube video
    vPlayer.loadVideoById( 'GEghz32qhiA', 0 );
}

function onPlayerStateChange( evt:Event ):void
{
    // if video is over
    if( Object(evt).data == 0 )
    {
        //do something when video is over
    }
}

// other player commands available - you need to make your own buttons for these
// vPlayer.mute();
// vPlayer.unMute();
// vPlayer.pauseVideo();
// vPlayer.playVideo();

// to start the whole process, call loadVideo();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've put the code in but unfortunately it says unexpected right brace at the end of the program, and when I get rid of that brace it says unexpected end to program, am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Its likely from the method onPlayerChange().  I edit it.  Try it with the new method.  Also, this code may not run without errors as I wrote it from memory, and this is just to get you started.  All of the pieces you need are there.  If you know as3 syntax well enough you should be able to cobble it together from what is there.